# It's not possible to perform a POST request with HTTPBody content in a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift

I can not go to the post method and that's why I do not load the website

```
 let url = URL(string: "\(Application.PROTOCOL)\(Application.DOMAIN)/index.php?loc=aaaaa")
 let body = "key=\(Application.KEY)&token=\(Application.TOKEN)"
 var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
 print("request: \(request)")
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
 request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
 self.webView.load(request as URLRequest)
 URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Got this:

`Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service`

`Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service`

Comment: can not go to the post method? maybe because your url is nil?

Comment: Some error? You need to provide more information.

Comment: @Kevinosaurio edited

Comment: did you added your webView before load the request? Your url is http or https?

Comment: @Kevinosaurio it is added to the load and the url is https

Comment: Your webview is added to the view by .xib (or storyboard) or programmatically?

Comment: storyboard ....